# Limit select dropdown options - angular

Tags: angular, css, angular5

Is there a way that a select tag has a limited number of results to display in the dropdown, and then scrollbar if there is more ?

This is my code :

```
   <select class="form-control" name="selectedOption" [(ngModel)]='selectedOption'>
        <option value="" [disabled]="true">Disabled</option>
        <option value="">All Options</option>
        <option *ngFor="let name of options" [ngValue]="name">{{name}}</option>
      </select>
```

And I want to display 8 results at first and a scrollbar if there is more.
If this can't be done with the select tag, what would be the best way to do it ?
A dropdown with links within a div and then an overflow on the div ?
What are your suggestions in how these things are better solved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onmousedown` along with `onblur` to handle the limit of options

```
<select onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}" onchange="this.blur()"  onblur="this.size=0;" class="form-control" name="selectedOption" [(ngModel)]='selectedOption'>
        <option value="" [disabled]="true">Disabled</option>
        <option value="">All Options</option>
        <option *ngFor="let name of options" [ngValue]="name">{{name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krqnum?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)